# insert Static HTML site to Drupal CMS

Tags: drupal

I would like to enter a static one page Html site to Drupal CMS,
But I did not find a clear way for the implementation of the process.

How can I insert my static site on Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Basic Page node, including your HTML code as the "Body" field of the node. Make sure you save your "Body" field as full HTML. Otherwise, some HTML tags could not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

With Bustikiller's solution you will be using template of Basic Page content type.

My suggestion is to create new content type, let's call it "test".

Then create a template file for it, name it node--test.tpl.php and place it in:

/sites/all/themes/your-theme-name/templates

(or change template name to fit your content type name)

Clear the cache and your new test content type will start using this new template.

Place your static html into that template file.

Create a node (page)  in that template file and when you open it your template file with your static html will be used.

If you want to have it editable instead of editable parts print field values..i.e. body field value...or value(s) of the fields you added to that content type.

That way your page will not share Basic Pace common html, but has it's own. But page and html templates will still be shared.

Comment: my static html has Css/js file
where should i place it and if there any change i must do in html file code
i am a beginner in drupal thank you for help